# Docusaurus Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for for large volume load

Tags: gitlab, jsx, markdown, docusaurus

I am working on using Docusaurus to create a central location for markdowns coming from many sources, I have written a GitLab plugin to load data from GitLab by querying the GitLab API using Axios and writing them under the "docs" directory under Docusaurus, so we are talking about thousands of markdowns, I keep getting issues related to broken markdown links which I set to ignore in the docusaurus.config.js file and that worked fine, but now I am getting lots of issues related to missing JSX tags, I do understand that I can do some post-processing to either escape the tags or close them if possible ... is there a way to make Docusaurus be more lenient toward this as this is a lot of post-processing and I keep finding more and more corner cases...?